# How can I issue payments from my business under my business' name?

Tags: small-business

I have a small business checking account with a bank, and a Wise business account.  Both of them send payments (wire transfers, ACH...) with their names appearing on the recipients' statement.  I'd like my business name to be listed as the originator of the payment for the recipient in their bank account and statement.  Similar to how my job pays me under the company name.

How are others doing this, and/or how can I do this?

I've asked both the bank and Wise if this is possible, and they've both told me no.

Comment: This is the flip side if being able to accept checks written to the business.usually you have to jump through some governmental hoops so the business is on record as existing (paperwork and fees, details vary), then you have to take that certification to the bank to have them open the account in the business's name rather than your own (but with you as signatory), Exact details vary by jurisdiction.

Comment: @keshlam My business is registered with the State and I have business accounts with both Wise and the bank under the business' name

Comment: Your company either initiates deposits directly or uses a third party payroll company that _does_ support identifying the root payer. It sounds like your bank and Wise do not. I have the same complaint about charges from PayPal that do not identify who sent it.